# Problems getting a site's https certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have an Android app that has some trouble with a site's certificate when connecting via https. As I'm experiencing trouble even when using a custom keystore with the certificates ("No peer certificate") I'm trying to get more information about the connection, handshake and certificates actually given by the server.

The version of openssl is follows:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

When I just try to get info about the certificates I get this response:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect [hostname]:443 </dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
3069977808:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:749:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

This is how Chrome describes the connection (sorry for the Norwegian text, but you get an idea of the connection and encryption type:
[image: adf]

Based on the info from Chrome I've tried different commands to get the certificates, but they all seem to fail. My top candidate was this one:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect [hostname]:443 -tls1_2 -cipher RC4-MD5
CONNECTED(00000003)
3069396176:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1258:SSL alert number 40
3069396176:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1414399499
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Anyone got any hints based on the info given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an SNI issue, where the server has no default certificate defined for non-SNI clients. Android included a version of Apaches httpclient which is known to not support SNI and your `openssl s_client` command also does not use SNI.

Please try `openssl s_client -servername hostname -connect ...` to use SNI and see if this helps.

Comment: Whoa, it seems like you're spot on! Thank you so much! :-D Using SNI I got the certificate. A bit off topic, but you seem to know a bit about the subject: When I get a "No peer certificate" from Apache's httpclient, do you know if it can be because of SNI issues? I see that the server doesn't return the intermediate certficate or anything.

Comment: Yes, this is probably also caused by the missing SNI support in Apache httpclient, as shipped with Android. See also http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-and-tlsv1-2-with-apache-httpclient for possible workarounds.

Comment: adding -servername <hostname> made my openssl s_client command work for the site I was working with.  Thanks!